# Objective C - NSNumber storing and retrieving longLongValue always prefixes with 0xFFFFFFFF

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber, long-long

I am trying to store a file size in bytes as an NSNumber.  I am reading the file download size from the NSURLResponse and that gives me a long long value and I then create an NSNumber object from that value and store it.  When I go to retrieve that value later, it comes back with all the higher bytes set as FFFFFFFF.

For example, I read in the size as 2196772870 bytes (0x82f01806) and then store it into the NSNumber.  When I get it back, I get -2098194426 bytes (0xffffffff82f01806).  I tried doing a binary AND with 0x00000000FFFFFFFF before storing the value in NSNumber but it still comes back as negative.  Code below:

```
long long bytesTotal = response.expectedContentLength;
NSLog(@"bytesTotal = %llx",bytesTotal);
[downloadInfo setFileTotalSize:[NSNumber numberWithInt:bytesTotal]];
//[downloadInfo setFileTotalSize:[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:bytesTotal]];
long long fileTotalSize = [[downloadInfo fileTotalSize] longLongValue];        
NSLog(@"fileTotalSize = %llx",fileTotalSize);
```

Output:

```
bytesTotal = 82f01806
fileTotalSize = ffffffff82f01806
```

Any suggestions?

Edit:  Completely forgot the setter for the downloadInfo object.

Comment: Why do you mask `bytesTotal` when creating `size`? What do you do with `size`? Where does `downloadInfo` come from?

Comment: @maddy It does the same thing whether I mask it or not.  downloadInfo is just an object that stores the file size so that I can display the total size in a view.

Comment: There's a big hole in the code you posted. How do you get from the `size` variable (which you don't log) to the `downloadInfo` variable? It seems to me that the messed up value happens somewhere in that missing set of details.

Comment: What is `downloadInfo` and `[downloadInfo fileTotalSize]`? - `long long fileTotalSize = [size longLongValue];` returns the correct value.

Comment: Sorry I completely forgot the setter for the fileTotalSize variable on the downloadInfo object.

Comment: @maddy No I meant in the post.  I still see this issue in my code.  I was trying to condense it for the post.

Comment: @rplankenhorn: What kind of object is `downloadInfo`? How is `fileTotalSize` and `setFileTotalSize` defined?

Comment: Do not use `numberWithInt:` with a `long long` value. Even better, use: `downloadInfo.fileTotalSize = @(bytesTotal);`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
[downloadInfo setFileTotalSize:[NSNumber numberWithInt:bytesTotal]];
```

`bytesTotal` is not an `int`, it's a `long long`, so you should be using `numberWithLongLong:`, not `numberWithInt:`.  Change it to:

```
[downloadInfo setFileTotalSize:[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:bytesTotal]];
```

The conversion is causing it to be sign extended to 64 bits, and the number starting with 8 appears to be a negative number so that bit gets extended all the way thru the upper long, causing it to be ffffffff.

Comment: I still see the issue whether I use numberWithLongLong or numberWithInt.